# Subdivided plane faces with same UVMap Texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, subdivision-surface

I have a plane subdivided with <kbd>W</kbd> *>Subdivide* into countless smaller faces.

I'd like to texturize all those faces with the same texture. For that i right-clicked a face <kbd>U</kbd> *>Unwrap* and added the texture to it. But now I would like to do this for all of those faces.

[image: Single texturized faces (left) and the whole plane Unwrap (right)]

When I select all faces and click <kbd>U</kbd>*>Unwrap* the Texture is spread over the whole surface, as can be seen in the figure below.

In other posts I read I could use <kbd>U</kbd>*>Reset*. When I do that I get every "plane-part" in the UV-Map Editor but lying all about each other.

Is there a way to drag every part over the full Map, when they lie over each other like in the image below? Other tutorials write if I do it like this using Reset, the whole Map should be filled. Is there something I did wrong?

[image: All selected plane parts are here as a line. If I take the line, I simply select the face of one single "plane part"...]

I am using textures without material, because the application I'm using it for works with that and blender 2.79 because I use a special addon which only works with this version

Comment: in the UV editor, in the toolbar at the top, try clicking>UV>pack islands.  That might do it.

Comment: If you delete all UV maps and add a new fresh one, each quad face will be given the full UV space.

Comment: Allens Solution seems to work. Thanks for your help.